# Population one table with different data arays and maintaining the table layout

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-table

```
 <table width="503" height="278" border="1">
        <tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td height="34" align="center" valign="middle" id="side"><strong>TEST</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><strong>METHOD</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><strong>COMPEDIA</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><strong>SPECIFICATION</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><strong>DETERMINED</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" id="side"><strong>REMARKS</strong></td>
        </tr>
         <?php foreach ($tests_requested_display2 as $value2)  ?><!--has values to populate the compedia and specification cells of the table-->
        <?php foreach ($tests_requested_display as $value) : ?> <!-- creates 3 dynamic rows-->
            <tr>
                <td height="56" align="center" valign="middle" id="side"><?php echo $value->name ?></td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">Weight</td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="compedia[]" cols="10" ><?php echo @$value2->compedia;?></textarea></td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="specification[]" cols="10"><?php echo @$value2->specification;?></textarea></td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">None Deviate</td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" id="side">COMPLIES</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>
```

The first foreach array with `$value`  contains 3 values which creates a table as defined above but with 3rows and 6 columns. I have a second foreach array $value2 has data that is to fill compedia and specification columns, if I echo `$value2->compedia` and `$value->specification`, it returns only the last value in the array out of six values and if I add end foreach same as for the `$value` array, it returns a weird result. What am I missing?

More info:

`print_r($tests_requested_display)` returns:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Dissolution ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Assay ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Uniformity of Weight ) ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Dissolution ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Assay ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Uniformity of Weight ) ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Dissolution ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Assay ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Uniformity of Weight ) )
```

and `print_r($tests_requested_display2)` returns:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Assay [compedia] => Caps [specification] => Tabs ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Dissolution [compedia] => Tabs [specification] => Caps ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Uniformity of Weight [compedia] => TabsCaps [specification] => CapsTabs ) ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Assay [compedia] => Caps [specification] => Tabs ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Dissolution [compedia] => Tabs [specification] => Caps ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Uniformity of Weight [compedia] => TabsCaps [specification] => CapsTabs ) ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Assay [compedia] => Caps [specification] => Tabs ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Dissolution [compedia] => Tabs [specification] => Caps ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Uniformity of Weight [compedia] => TabsCaps [specification] => CapsTabs ) )
```

The result that I expect as an example:

```
<table width="503" height="278" border="1">
        <tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td height="34" align="center" valign="middle" id="side"><strong>TEST</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><strong>METHOD</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><strong>COMPEDIA</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><strong>SPECIFICATION</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><strong>DETERMINED</strong></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" id="side"><strong>REMARKS</strong></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td height="56" align="center" valign="middle" id="side">Assay</td>            
            <td align="center" valign="middle">Weight</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="compedia[]" cols="10">Caps</textarea></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="specification[]" cols="10">Tabs</textarea></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">None Deviate</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" id="side">COMPLIES</td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td height="56" align="center" valign="middle" id="side">Dissolution</td>            
            <td align="center" valign="middle">Weight</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="compedia[]" cols="10">TabsCaps</textarea></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="specification[]" cols="10">CapsTabs</textarea></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">None Deviate</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" id="side">COMPLIES</td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td height="56" align="center" valign="middle" id="side">Uniformity</td>            
            <td align="center" valign="middle">Weight</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="compedia[]" cols="10">Tabs</textarea></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="specification[]" cols="10">Caps</textarea></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">None Deviate</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" id="side">COMPLIES</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: You only close one `foreach` but you open two... you can't really do that. What do you mean by a "weirded result"?

Comment: It would be handy if you could provide (a) the content of the `$tests_requested_display` and `$tests_requested_display2`, and (b) what you want your final table to look like

Comment: I have added more information so as to make the question clearer

Comment: It's still difficult to see what you're trying to achieve - the desired result you have shown above contains just three rows, whereas the php code you have post, combined with the print_r results, would give you 9 rows. It looks like `$tests_requested_display2` contains the information you're trying to tabularise, but I can't tell how `$tests_requested_display comes into the equation... if indeed it needs to be involved in the table generation at all?

Answer (score 0):

So the syntax is a little suspect to me, but keep in mind I'm pretty new to PHP in general so it may be okay. However, here is a modified version of the code that should do the trick for you:

```
<?php foreach ($tests_requested_display2 as $value2) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($tests_requested_display as $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td height="56" align="center" valign="middle" id="side"><?=$value->name?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">Weight</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="compedia[]" cols="10" ><?=@$value2->compedia?></textarea></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="specification[]" cols="10"><?=@$value2->specification?></textarea></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">None Deviate</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" id="side">COMPLIES</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

but it still won't solve this:

> **if i echo $value2->compedia and $value->specification, it returns only the last value in the array out of six values**

because that list isn't iterated until all three values of the inner list is iterated. So from that perspective you could swap the loops and you would get three sets of six rows, **or** you could wrap the `td` tags and build the proper string value for the six values you want. It's not clear **at all** what you're really expecting that to do.

Comment: Hello, your solution itterates creating a total of 9 rows. I have added more information to what i expected from that code listing